# How can I validate across properties using Google appengine ndb?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Say I have a class with two properties like so:

```
class Banana(ndb.Model):
    is_delicious = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)
    is_rotten = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)
```

A rotten `Banana` entry cannot be delicious. How can I prevent saving a delicous, rotten banana to the datastore?

I can override the `__init__` method as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25786896/2532070), but this does not prevent someone *updating* the banana to an impossible state.

The docs show a [validator option](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#options) but this doesn't work across fields.

How can I validate two fields of my model against one another to prevent saving an object in an incorrect state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this does not prevent someone updating the banana to an impossible state.

Datastore provides almost zero schema enforcement on its own.

You could open the web console for your Datastore (https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities) select an entity and start deleting properties off of it, even if you `ndb` code has `required=True` when defining the property

[image]

In the picture I could edit the field `completed` to be a boolean instead of a date-time and then appengine would throw an exception everytime this entity is fetched via `ndb`.

So I don't know where that leaves you. You could go the `__init__` route

You could put the check in `_pre_put_hook`:

```
class Banana(ndb.Model):
    is_delicious = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)
    is_rotten = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    def _pre_put_hook(self):
        if self.is_delicious and self.is_rotten:
            raise Exception("A rotten Banana entry cannot be delicious")
```

You could have a `ComputedProperty` do the check:

```
class Banana(ndb.Model):
    is_delicious = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)
    is_rotten = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)

    def _is_valid(self):
        if self.is_delicious and self.is_rotten:
            raise Exception("A rotten Banana entry cannot be delicious")
        return True

    is_valid = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self._is_valid())
```

But all of these will only work when the db is being access by your `ndb` code